# How can I archive old contacts out of My Contacts?

Tags: google-contacts, cloud

On an Android (6.0), how can I archive old Google contacts where they do not show up in my contacts but they are listed in either:

- the google contacts website under *other contacts*
- archived in another app/cloud storage securely.

Ideally moving them from the archive to my contacts list would be doable from a mobile app, or the archive service would have a mobile website where they are accessible.

To clarify: I don't want to delete them forever or be inaccessible on mobile.

Answer (score 4):

Just with one account also you can achieve this.

1. In contacts app, go to menu and create a new label like "Archive"
2. Tap on label and add contacts.
3. From menu go to settings, and in "contacts to display" select customized, and expand your google account, now here all labels will be shown. Select all labels except Archive.

Now contacts moved to Archive label will not be shown in list.

Comment: Good idea. I never thought of this!

Comment: I wish you had a similar answer for bookmarks. Those old bookmarks are cluttering up my Android chrome.

Comment: For bookmarks in Android chrome, we only have folder segregation. Edit bookmarks and move to separate bookmark folders to avoid cluttering up.

Comment: Is this answer still valid? In my "Customize view" if I select the top checkbox which is "My Contacts" then all contacts are shown. It seems like I need to do the inverse: create a label for the ones I want shown and only select it, which is annoying.

Comment: Normally when you expand your Google account in customized view, then selecting account itself will select all labels. Then just uncheck Archive or label which you don't want to see. This way you need to move only which you do not want to see.

Comment: And now a days almost every phone, even stock app gives block options. So all the disturbing ads & callers just block directly from call app, instead using labels for them.

Answer (score 3):

**Tip:** Using a computer may make it easier to do this. However, you can also do it on a mobile browser.

1. In your mobile phone, make sure you have synced your contact list to Google Contacts.
2. Open **"Google Contacts"** at https://contacts.google.com/ preferably on a desktop or laptop.
3. Select any one contact by clicking the checkbox.
4. Open the **"Selection actions"** menu in the header toolbar and click **"All"**.
5. Go through your contact list and de-select the contacts you want to keep. The checkbox must be cleared for those contacts.
6. For the remaining contacts that are still checked, you are going to archive them. Click the *three dots* icon in the menu and click **"Hide from contacts"**. (This will move them into the *"Other contacts"* list.)
7. In your mobile phone, check the sync to make sure the archived contacts have disappeared from the phone's contact list.

If you wish to add any contact back, just search for it in the **"Google Contacts"** website. Select the contact under **"Other contacts"** and click **"Add to contacts"**. This will bring the contact back into your phone's contact list.

Comment: For access in mobile, you can visit the same website in your mobile browser. That way you can still search for archived contacts, and add them back if necessary, without cluttering your phonebook.

Answer (score 2):

I have found one solution: have multiple accounts, your primary and backup/archive. Use the new Google contacts app to bulk select and move the contacts to the archive account. Then set either contacts app, either the stock app or the new cloud one, to only show the primary contacts. But Karthiks answer above is better.

Comment: I like this one more than the other; moving old contacts to a separate archive account and then removing the archive account makes it easy to prevent messengers such as WhatsApp from uploading the old, archived contacts.